# C# Unity no detecta la pulsación de flecha de arriba

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

resulta que estoy empezando con unity así que estoy viendo unos tutoriales.
En un tutorial el hombre le dice al programa que si se presiona la flecha de arriba o el click izquierdo del mouse, empiece un efecto parallax.

El problema es que no me detecta la pulsación de la flecha.

Este es el código:

```
if (gameState == GameState.Idle && (Input.GetKeyDown("up") || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
    {
        gameState = GameState.Playing;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Es porque en ves de `"up"` dentro de Input.GetKeyDown() seria `"UpArrow"`si no checa este link: https://docs.unity3d.com/es/530/ScriptReference/KeyCode.html

Comment: pues resulta que ahora funciona con "up" no entiendo porque

Comment: Bueno pues quien sabe pero prefiero trabajar con el `"UpArrow"` para evitar problemas.

Comment: En ese contexto "up" no es nada, por lo tanto es imposible que te funcione correctamente. La única forma de que funcione es que hayas añadido esa posibilidad en el apartado "Input" de "Project Settings", entonces no te podría decir nada. Si te funciona, no es por esa línea de código y por lo tanto tendrás un código mal estructurado. No te estoy llamando mentiroso ni cirticando, solo te estoy avisando de que algo pasa en tu código, si es que funciona como dices, y puede acarrearte problemas en el futuro o no. Si no es importante (el proyecto) olvídate de ello, pero si es importante, revísalo.

Comment: Tienes razón, hace un tiempo que no trabajaba en este proyecto y me había olvidado de que lo añadí en "input".